# To dine somebody?

Tags: grammar, verbs

Here is a line from Sir Walter Scott's journal:

> We expect a raid of folks to visit us this morning, whom we must have dined before our misfortunes. Save time, wine, and money, these misfortunes—and so far are convenient things.

I'm not sure of the whole meaning of the first sentence. Did he mean "have dined *with*" instead of just "have dined"? Surely cannibalism is out of the question?

I guess Sir Walter Scott is expressing a certain impatience with these folks, and wishing that he was ill so as to avoid dining with them. And in that case would "whom we will have to dine with before our misfortunes" be more clear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Used transitively as here, it means, in the OED’s definition:

> To furnish or provide (a person) with a dinner; to entertain at
>   dinner; to accommodate for dining purposes.

This use is very old. The OED’s earliest citation is from 1399.

Comment: +1 We still speak of 'wining and dining' guests.

Comment: We do indeed, and the classicial scholar Maurice Bowra claimed that he was a man more dined against than dining.

Comment: Day Lewis said that Bowra was like strychnine, best taken in small doses.

Comment: But rather funnier.

Comment: @StoneyB If we happen to be Alanis Morrisette, we may even speak of ‘wining, dining, sixty-nining’ someone (but not hearing a damn words they say).

Answer (score 2):

"whom we must have dined"

Who we must have invited for dinner or entertained, before misfortune struck us.

He is further saying  that, misfortune is a blessing in disguise as it is saving him money, time and wine, as because of the 'excuse' of misfortune he is no longer obligated to entertain these people.

Comment: The "dinner party" had been postponed because of *misfortunes* thus "we expect... this morning" clearly infers that guests are arriving that same day.

Comment: @Mari-LouA This is April of 1826, shortly after Scott's publishing house collapsed and he himself was financially ruined. I don't think the dinner is postponed; rather, because his 'misfortunes'  are widely known his guests will no longer expect him to offer them dinner.

Comment: The meaning is right, but that ‘to’ in the beginning of the quote is nonsensical—you dine someone, you do not dine to them.